# The type not mapped issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, audit-trail

I have this class in my Domain-project :

```
public class Person: EntityObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have a repository in my DataAccess-project:

```
public class PersonRepository
{
    DatabaseContext DbContext { get; }

    public PersonRepository(DatabaseContext dbContext)
    {
        this.DbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Person> GetAll()
    {
        return DbContext.Persons.ToList();
    }

    public virtual void SaveChanges(Person persoon)
    {

        // configure auditing
        DbContext.Audit<Person, PersonHistory>(
            (record, action) => new PersonHistory()
            {
                ID = record.Field<Person, int>(f => f.ID),
                Name = record.Field<Person, string>(f => f.Name),
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                CreatedBy = "Simon",
                ChangedBy = "Simon",
                ChangedDate = DateTime.Now,
                ChangeType = action.ToString()
            },
            (ph) => DbContext.PersonHistory.Add(ph));

        DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

My dbcontext is in the DataAccess-project as well and looks as follows:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<PersonHistory> PersonHistory { get; set; }
}
```

I've added an extension-method to provide the audittrailing.

```
public static class DbContextExtension
{
    public static void Audit<TFromType, TToType>(this DbContext context,Func<IDataRecord, EntityState, TToType> mapping,Action<TToType> addToContext)
    {
        ObjectContext ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
        ctx.SavingChanges += new EventHandler((o, e) => CreateAuditRecord<TFromType, TToType>(ctx, mapping, addToContext));
    }

    private static void CreateAuditRecord<TFromType, TToType>(
       ObjectContext context,
       Func<IDataRecord, EntityState, TToType> mapping,
       Action<TToType> addToContext)
    {
        // get a list of changes to audit
        IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> entities =
            from e in context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
                EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Deleted)
            where
                e.IsRelationship == false &&
                typeof(TFromType).IsAssignableFrom(e.Entity.GetType())
            select e;

        foreach (ObjectStateEntry item in entities)
        {
            // map the changed item to an audit record entry
            TToType auditRecord = mapping(item.OriginalValues, item.State);
            // and add it to the object context so that it is persisted for us
            addToContext(auditRecord);
        }
    }

    public static T Field<E, T>(this IDataRecord record, Expression<Func<E, T>> propertySelector)
        where E : EntityObject
    {
        MemberExpression memberExpression = propertySelector.Body as MemberExpression;
        MemberInfo propertyInfo = memberExpression.Member;

        int fieldIndex = record.GetOrdinal(propertyInfo.Name);
        return Field<T>(record, fieldIndex);
    }

    public static T Field<T>(this IDataRecord record, int ordinal)
    {
        object value = record.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? null : record.GetValue(ordinal);
        return (T)value;
    }
}
```

Now when I run my application I get the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The type 'CoBen.Dossier.Domain.Person' was not
>   mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using
>   the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that
>   the type was defined as a class, is not primitive or generic, and does
>   not inherit from EntityObject.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The error says your Person class cannot inherit from EntityObject. Have you checked the relevance of that?

Comment: When i remove the inheritance from EntityObject I get problems in my public static T Field<E, T> since the E there has to be an EntityObject.

Or do you now of another good way to do audittrailing without writing the audit trail to one big audit-table but to tables per entity (like Person => PersonHistory) ?